# Problem connecting redis and django in GCP

Tags: django, google-app-engine, redis, google-cloud-memorystore

I have deployed a Redis instance using GCP Memorystore. 
I also have a django app deployed using App Engine. However, I am facing problems connecting these 2. Both are deployed in the same timezone. 
The package that I'm using is django_redis. When I try to login to admin page I face a connection error. 
The error is:

```
Exception Value: Error 110 connecting to <Redis instance IP>:6379. Connection timed out.
Exception Location: /env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py in connect, line 557
```

In settings.py I use:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("<Redis instance IP>", 6379)],
        },
    },
}

CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": 'redis://<Redis instance IP>/0',
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient"
        }
    }
}
```

Note: With locally installed Redis and  set to localhost, everything works fine.

Comment: Shouldn't your location be: redis://<Redis instance IP>:<Redis Instance port>/0

Answer (score 1):

In order to connect to Memorystore, you have to set up a VPC Network for your application, and add that connection into `app.yaml` into property `vpc_access_connector`. It's described here in docs: [Connecting to a VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/connecting-vpc)